Cross Account Cloudfront Trusted Key Groups for Signing
I have an organization with the following structure (simplified for this)
Root Account  
\-\> Account A (Production)  
\-\> Account B (Staging)  
\-\> Account C (Development)

Each of these workloads has a set of cloudfront distributions in for various different things.
We want to restrict access to staging/development and some production workloads using signed cookies. I don't however want to use the root account for this; I want to use the trusted key groups that AWS recommends.
The trusted key groups, I can't get to work across accounts however.
I have tried looking for resource sharing the key groups; this doesn't appear to be available.
I have tried using the same public/private key pair in all accounts but the key pair id is different and therefore can't be used.
